celery worker with sqs to consume arbitrary messages from outside
does anyone know if a celery worker can receive and consume messages from a sqs where the messages are pushed to the sqs by outside applications?
I cannot find any resources on this. Another pointers would be appreciated.
There are a lot of resources of connecting celery to sqs and then pushing tasks onto the queue and processing them but I want to push arbitrary messages (of different format) into the queue and have celery receive and process these in a task.
Most resources online related to celery sending and receiving messages to sqs.
